# Does Doxygen/headerdoc supports swift 4.0?

Tags: ios, swift4, doxygen, headerdoc

We are currently planning to create the documents using comments.
So any one have any idea how to achieve that.
As i have checked most of the post that Doxygen/headerdoc don't support Swift.

Comment: Did you try something? I.e. created a small swift project and ran doxygen over it ? What are the results, post some code.

Comment: @albert yes i have created a small swift project and ran in doxygen. Doxygen generated index.html but on running index.html found empty pages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, neither HeaderDoc nor Doxygen support Swift , you can use markDown and produce document pages with [Jazzy](https://github.com/realm/jazzy) and here is a tutorial for it [Swift Markdown](https://www.appcoda.com/swift-markdown/)

## Update

Now you can use **DocC** check tutorial here [Tutorial](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/238/how-to-document-your-project-with-docc) with Xcode 13 and Apple [DocC](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/docc) framework

Comment: @sh-khan thank you, Also can i add my design doc images in this jazzy documentation ?